# Suppress console output of player commands

Tags: java, console, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a bukkit plugin that allows players to lock chests with a password. To protect the players I would like to keep the password from the prying eyes of even the server operator.

I would like to hide the console text that is printed when a player uses a command. For instance, when a player types, /gamemode 1, the console prints out the command and who used it. Is there any way to stop this? Maybe intercept it and wipe it, or garble it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I looked around at those plugins, and they're much more complicated than what I need to do this simple thing, so I thought I would post my solution for anybody who stumbles upon this.

What you want to do is create a filter with the java.util.logging.Filter interface. In that you override the isLoggable() function. For my case, this is my exact object that I made.

```
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {

    if(record.getMessage().contains("issued server command: /login")) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
            }
      }
}
```

Then the only other thing you have to do is add this filter to the server logger. The exact line I used is:

```
    CustomFilter filter = new CustomFilter();
    plugin.getServer().getLogger().setFilter(filter);
```

Where plugin is the instance of the plugin in the main class.

Hope this helps anybody who finds this.

Comment: Thanks for this but just be aware that simply checking if the message contains that text isn't a good idea. Maybe I'm being paranoid, but players could stop their chat messages from being logged by having "issued server command: /login" in the message.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple plug-ins designed for doing this, but neither one is still maintained.

[ConsoleFilter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-consolefilter-v1-1-0-filter-or-modify-any-console-message-1-1-r8-1-2-5-r1-0.32093/&ei=tVncUfr8LsSXrAGhmIDgCg&usg=AFQjCNFZdeTF7EhP4QTF_sialI9DqnP9dw%20Console%20Filter)

[BlockConsoleMessages](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.bukkit.org%2Fbukkit-plugins%2Fblockconsolemessages%2F&ei=tVncUfr8LsSXrAGhmIDgCg&usg=AFQjCNF2aESryiuPXg6kGbRrG5bLdKMPLQ&cad=rja)

One of them may work for you, or you may be able to find the code in them that does what you want.

Comment: Awesome, this will work great. now that I know this is possible, I can go about making things more secure for the players, cause invariably, they will use their everything-password :P